# Разрешить просмотр только через ПО

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Пишу программу на Cefsharp. Возник вопрос. Не хочется держать рядом с программой папки со скриптами, шаблоном, стилями и тд.
Вопрос: если сделать все это на хостинге, как разрешить просмотр данной страницы только через запущенную программу, но не напрямую при переходе на IP или URL?

Пример: есть программа, при запуске которой идет сверка отправленного ключа (доступ к программе). Программа отправляет запрос на сайт и получает ответ. Но... Если напрямую перейти, то в этом получим следущее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обьясните новичку, как реализовать? 
Заранее спасибо :)

Еще пример, приложение 4GAME. Так же на платформе Chromium. Напрямую переход выдает 403 ошибку, но в программе все прекрасно отображает.

Comment: Проверяйте UserAgent или любой другой заголовок на стороне сервера. Но это вы сами понимаете, не какая то там защита, простая проверка того, что заход был именно с приложения, не более и это естественно легко подменить.

Comment: Естественно, защита не нужна. Просто хочется скрыть от лишних глаз.

Comment: Ну тогда простого заголовка в запросе должно быть достаточно. Кстати, с 4Game не удалось воспроизвести пример. Любая страница у меня успешно открывается в браузере. Например https://launcher.ru.4game.com/game/bns-ru/play. 403 выдает только ru-mds.4game.com, но это CDN, базовая их страница, на которой нету толком инфы (например если добавить путь https://ru-mds.4game.com/images/widgets/w600_h400/5b1bc473-9d94-4115-bbe1-6b249c7a9845.png, то доступ есть). Так что у них нету проверки на приложение или что то еще, только авторизация.

Comment: Хм... Я не нашел этих страниц. Да, вы правы.
А что именно сверять в заголовке, не подскажете?

Comment: Мне кажется простого [UserAgent](https://8500.ru/user-agent/) будет достаточно.

Comment: можно использовать сразу 2 штуки -- UserAgent и скрытые параметры вызова страницы. Например %check="thisIsMySecretParam". Добавляем на страницы проверку как на юзерагент так и на наявность и значение "check". А в строчке адреса твоей апликухи автоматом вырезать этот параметр что бы скрыть от пользователя. При переходе же на другую страницу - автоматом добавлять :) И то и другое не даст открыть сайт с простого браузера. По крайней мере без колупания твоей проги)